# I am trying to check if two class objects equal in content but I get java.lang.StackOverflowError when I run my tests for the project

Tags: java, class

This is my code for the equal method but it throws java.lang.StackOverflowError when I run the code. It doesn't do it when I use == instead of equals but that wouldn't give me the right answer. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong, I am still new to programming so kindly excuse me if I am overlooking something obvious. Thank you

```
  @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if ( ! ( other instanceof Vote) ) {
      return false;
    }
    Vote otherVote = (Vote) other;
    if (this.equals(otherVote)){
      return true;
      }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You overrode the equals method, then call it again in the body of the method...so you wrote a method that calls itself, hence the stack overflow error.

Comment: `equals()` calls `equals()` which calls `equals()` which calls `equals()` which calls `equals()` which calls `equals()` which calls `equals()` ... Where does the actual comparison happen?

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there another way that I could approach this other than using == for it?

Comment: You have not shown the complete definition of the `Vote` class. What makes two objects of class `Vote` "equal"?  I assume `Vote` has member fields, and to decide if two `Vote`s are equal you must compare the values of those member fields.  _That_ is what your `equals()` method should be comparing.

Comment: As others have mentioned, ideally you need to define your own `equals()`. But if you insist on using `Object.equals()` you can also call it by using `super.equals(otherVote)` instead of `this.equals(otherVote)`

Answer (score 0):

You overrode `equals()` and it calls itself. The method `equals()` **is not** recursive and since you didn't put a condition to stop it calling itself then you receive `StackOverFlowException`.